# Get url so can send it in an email

Tags: codeigniter

I need to get the url and place it in my code so it can be sent has a link in an email.

SO if i have localhost/interiors/accessories/clocks/mantle-clocks/mantle-clock

I need to get this url so i can place it my controller to send it as an email link.

Comment: If you don't have an ID somewhere that would translate into that URL, then you're doing something WRONG, the easiest way if you have that id is to send it to your email form & retrieve the url from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $_SERVER global. It should contain the information you need, e.g. REQUEST_URI etc

Comment: I have tried $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] also tried current_url() but still no joy. So the link above then shows a form to send to a friend, which then uses a controller called send and a method called sendToFriend but this uri is not sending has it should be.

Comment: I've had to put my code for sending the email in the same page in order to get the correect URL by using $_SERVER['REUQEST_URI']

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple you can call current_url() helper method of Codeigniter

```
$url = current_url();
```

Use this url to send in email. Or if this is not what you want than you will have to manually generate url.

```
$url = http://localhost/interiors/accessories/clocks/mantle-clocks/mantle-clock';
```

Comment: I can't do it manually it need to grab it from the URL has its an e-commerce store that will have over 500 products in. I'll try yout first option although I belive this doesn't do what I need it to either

Comment: $url = current_url(); doesn't work either, tried eveything now